# Mock Bluetooth device appium

Tags: android, testing, bluetooth, mocking, appium

I am currently testing a native mobile app using appium automation with java. Currently testing with android. In that app, I need to connect to a Bluetooth device which actually a physical device.

For example, if i click 'connect to a x device' then it will look for that physical device using device id and show that device in the Bluetooth device list within in the app. Currently I don't have that physical device to pair. So I need to mock it.

How to mock this device to show up as  fake device in the list so I can select and continue to next step.

Is there any way I can do it programmatically or any inbuilt function from appium to do it.

Comment: Is the device using Bluetooth Classic or Bluetooth Low Energy?

Comment: Hi Michael, its BLE

Comment: Thank you for the info! There are apps available that can simulate a BLE device for testing if you have a second phone, the [BLE Peripheral SImulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.webbluetoothcg.bletestperipheral&hl=de&gl=US) for Android for example